# AODV Routing protocol on Raspberry Pi model B ?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

is it possible to run the AODV routing protocol on rpi ?

Comment: You'd be better off asking about this on our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It should be, but you may want/have to implement it yourself.  There is an [out-of-tree kernel module](http://www.antd.nist.gov/wctg/aodv_kernel/), but it is for a version of the kernel from almost 15 years ago and is very unlikely to work with current ones, including anything that is available for the pi.

However, [according to this](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/aodv.htm) AODV is wrapped inside UDP/IP, i.e., it is a high (application) level protocol.  Someone looks to have done a [fairly recent open source implementation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aodvuu/) for linux that runs as a userspace daemon; it also refers to old kernels but I think that is just because the source is old.  It probably will not matter.